# Angular 2 Testing PrimeNG ConfirmationDialog

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, primeng, primeng-dialog

I'm writing jasmine unit test for following code:

```
this.confirmationService.confirm({
  message: 'Are you sure that you want to delete?',
  accept: () => {
   //some code to test
  }
});
```

How I can fake clicking of Yes in the dialog, to test code inside
accept() function?

Comment: there's nothing that says you can't use JQuery to force the click event.

Answer (score 0):

In your template:

```
<p-confirmDialog #confirmDialog header="Confirmation" icon="fa fa-question-circle" width="425"></p-confirmDialog>
```

In your component:

```
@ViewChild('confirmDialog') confirmDialog: ConfirmDialog;
```

then you're able to invoke `confirmDialog.accept()`.

Comment: You shouldn't add additional component properties only for test. To test it properly you should mock confirm function and call fake accept function inside to simulate correct behavior

Answer (score 0):

You can create spy like this:

```
spyOn(confirmationService, 'confirm').and.callFake((params: Confirmation) => {
    params.accept();
});
```